# 3D linear surface

Tags: opengl, graphics, interpolation

I need to make interpolation and build a linear surface using OpenGL, but I have a problem with algorithm.
In my book(Rodgers Computer Graphics) is said that the equation of linear surface is 
Q(u,w) = P(u,0)(1-w) + P(u,1) * w. But I can`t find a way to use it. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

*Make a grid and approximate by quads.*

### Pseudo-code

```
density = 0.01;
for (a = 0.0; a <= 1.0; a += density) {
    for (b = 0.0; b <= 1.0; b += density) { 
        draw-quad(
                  Q(a,           b), 
                  Q(a + density, b),
                  Q(a + density, b + density),
                  Q(a,           b + density));
    }
}
```